# How can you make bitcoinj not use change addresses?

Tags: bitcoinj, change

My question is related to `bitcoinj` library but not limited by it. `bitcoinj` will create new change address after every transaction. It will manage them transparently, but let say I want to use this library for merchant payment service. I don't have privacy issue, opposite to that I want to use the service as transparent as it could be. That would be one address per customer to receive money from them one load address to supply money from exchange and one change address.

Is it in general good idea or could there be a security issue? As I said before, privacy is not issue.

If that would be ok, what is the best way to stop `bitcoinj` from using change addresses and use just one instead?